# What happens if the ouputs of a resolver are connected?

Tags: motor, sensor

It seems like the classical design of a resolver involves 6 wires, 2 for power the primary coil and 4 to represent the sin and cos output of the secondary coils.

[image]

I have an very amateur question. What happens if I tie S3 to S4?

Something like this:

[image]

Can I still use these signals to determine angular position and velocity?

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: Your diagram shows S3 connecting to S4 (not S2).

Comment: What will change about the signal though?

Comment: That's the way it's usually done.